# Read a file with two words per line and save the words in an efficient way in C

Tags: c

I have a text file which has a pair of words in each line and I used this to read them:

```
for (i=0, j=0; (c=fgetc(fp))!=EOF; i++){
    if (c == ' '){
        pares[j].par1[i] = '\0';

        for (i=0; (c=fgetc(fp))!= '\n'; i++){
            pares[j].par2[i] = c;
        }
        j++;            
        i= -1;
    }
    else{
        pares[j].par1[i]=c;
    }
}

n_pares = j;
fclose(fp);
```

"pares" is a structure which has the first word of the line (par1) and the second word (par2), I know I didn't need to do this. But I don't know if this is the most efficient method to do this. Because in Python I would just use the function split() and I wouldn't need to do the for loop. Can anybody tell me if there is a more efficient way?

Comment: The two last lines of the code don't matter here

Comment: Please do not try to describe the structure: post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If the code works, but you want it better, perhaps post on CodeReview? PS: I would read with `fgets` and split with `strtok`.

Comment: "most efficient method" in what?  Execution speed (speed is throttled by I/O, user code makes little difference.) Source code smallness - consider  [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com).  Efficiency in review? (A well , easy to read and prove code).  Memory usage?  Code posted has _functional_ ambiguities/problems. suggest fixing that and then proceed to "efficiency".

Comment: Efficiency meaning speed!

Comment: How big is the file? The most 'efficient' is to read it all in one gulp if the file is smaller than available memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than reading character by character, it's generally more efficient to allocate a large line buffer once, read the line into that buffer, and process it into more appropriately sized pieces.

```
char line[1024];
while(fgets(line, 1024, fp) != NULL) {
    ...now process line...
}
```

Splitting a line in C is a bit more difficult than in higher level languages. The standard function is [`strtok`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm) (string token) and it's a little funny to use.

```
    const char sep[] = " \t\n";

    for(
        char *token = strtok( line, sep );
        token != NULL;
        token = strtok( NULL, sep )
    ) {
        printf("%s ", token);
    }

    printf("\n");
```

What happening is `strtok` remembers its place while looking through a string, but it can only do it for one string at a time. Passing it in a string resets it back to the start. So `strtok( line, sep )` starts the process on `line`, and `strtok( NULL, sep )` gets the next token on `line` until there's none left.

This global state is shared by all calls to `strtok`, so it's not even safe to call another function while using `strtok`, that function might also call `strtok` and reset the state.

The non-standard [`strtok_r`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok_r) is safer, it uses a variable to remember where it is. [`strsep`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strsep) has a better interface, but it is also non-standard.

These all work by modifying the string being iterated through. `token` is just a pointer into `line`. For example, if we had something like this:

```
// Let's say line is pointing at memory location 1000
// 'U' is at 1000, 'p' is at 1001, ' ' is at 1002, etc...
line = 1000
 |
 v
"Up down\n\0"
```

The first call to `char *token = strtok( line, sep );` results in this.

```
line = 1000
 |
 v
"Up\0down\n\0"
 ^
 |
token = 1000
```

`token` is pointing to the start of the string, but notice that the space has been replaced with a null byte. This lets you use `token` as the string `"Up"` without allocating fresh memory. Note that the string is modified!

The second `token = strtok( NULL, sep )` causes `token` to move.

```
line = 1000
 |
 v
"Up\0down\0\0"
     ^
     |
    token = 1003
```

The newline at the end has been replaced with a null byte. Now `token` contains the string `"down"`, but it's just pointing at memory shared with `line`. If you print `line`, you'll get `"Up"`.

On the final `token = strtok( NULL, sep )`, `token` will be set to NULL because there's no more non-separator characters. `line` remains modified.

```
line = 1000
 |
 v
"Up\0down\0\0"

token = NULL
```

Point is, you can't store `token` because it points at `line` and `line` is going to change next iteration of the loop. You have to make a copy of the string `token` is pointing at with something like [`strdup`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup). This is very memory efficient, it avoids unnecessary memory allocation and copying, but it can be a bit difficult to wrap your head around if you're coming from a higher level language.

Comment: @ibp4 Technically no, because all strings are pointers. That aside, you can, as you demonstrated, but not efficiently. You're gonna have to get used to pointers if you're going to program in C. It's kinda like asking if you can code Python without objects.

Comment: Of course, i agree, it's just that in this special occasion i can't use pointers. But thanks a lot!

Comment: @ibp4 You're already using pointers. `pares[j].par1` is a `char *` pointer (ie. a string). `fp` is a `FILE *` pointer. You might want to get some clarification on that restriction. Anyhow, if this is a restricted exercise, I wouldn't worry about efficiency.